# Change ImageView url with using Databinding when i click on button

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my simple application i try to update `ImageView` url to change image on application, i create simple databinding class to implementing that, but not working and i dont get any error

My model class as `User`:

```
class User(baseContext: Context) : BaseObservable() {
    val context:Context = baseContext
    var username: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
    var profilePicUrl: String? = null
        @Bindable
        set(profilePicUrl) {
            field = profilePicUrl
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.profilePicUrl)
        }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("android:profilePicUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
            if (!imageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(view)
            }
        }
    }

    @Bindable
    fun getProfilePicVisibility(): Int {
        return if (profilePicUrl == null || profilePicUrl!!.isEmpty()) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

`LoginActivity` class:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: LoginActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login_activity)
    binding.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginViewModelFactory(this)).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    val user = User(baseContext)
    user.username = "my name"
    user.password = "my family"
    user.profilePicUrl = ""

    binding.user = user

    val handlers = ClickHandler(this)
    handlers.user = user
    binding.handlers = handlers
}
```

and then `ClickHandler` class

```
class ClickHandler(private val context: Context) {
    var user: User? = null

    fun clickOnLoginButton(view: View) {
        user?.profilePicUrl = "https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/1-370x247.jpg"
    }
}
```

after clicking on button i expect ImageView url can be update and `loadImage` function can be work to get image from url and attach into that

my simplified layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="ir.instacheeta.application.ui.login.viewModel.LoginViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="ir.instacheeta.application.ui.login.model.User" />

        <variable
            name="handlers"
            type="ir.instacheeta.application.ui.login.viewModel.ClickHandler" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_10">

        ...

                        <Button
                            ...
                            android:onClick="@{handlers::clickOnLoginButton}"
                            ... />

                        ...

            ...

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                ...
                android:profilePicUrl="@{user.profilePicUrl}"
                android:src="@drawable/img_wizard_1"
                android:tint="@color/mdtp_white"
                android:visibility="@{user.profilePicVisibility, default=gone}"
                ... />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: While debugging are you able to confirm that in your binding adapter you are actually entering inside your if statement?

Comment: how are you setting the variables like ViewModel, handlers? Is your click function working?

Comment: clicking work fine. i tested that by Toast

Comment: and how are you updating your user object? since in the provided code, your user object will always be null

Comment: in login activiry i create new instance from that, maybe you have right. and my user is not correct

Comment: yes, but in handler, you have declared another reference which is null so you should pass the user object from your xml in clickOnLoginButton method as parameter

Comment: thanks, could you show me how can i do that by code?

Answer (score -1):

You have declared user variable in your handler class which is null so you should pass the user object from your XML in a clickOnLoginButton method as a parameter.

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    ...
</data>

<Button
...
android:onClick="@{(view) -> handler.clickOnLoginButton(view,user)}"
... />
```

and update your method as well

```
fun clickOnLoginButton(view: View,user:User)
```

Comment: after adding `<import type="android.view.View" />` that resolve your code problem but after click on button imageview url couldnt update

Comment: can you check by removing android:visibility="@{user.profilePicVisibility, default=gone} from imageview. I just tested the same and it works for me

Comment: i removed and check again, url couldn't change after clicking on button

Comment: problem is after clicking on button BindingAdapter as loadImage don't work again and that only work once